# How to get server time with JS AND PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

I am creating a site where I get the time from the server in php and then pass it to a JS variable, this to perform some other actions.

This is my example of what I have:

Clock.php file: In this file I get the server time

```
<?php 

echo $s = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');

?>
```

Index.php file: In this file I get the result of the echo set in the file clock.php.

```
    <?php include("reloj.php"); ?>
    <input type="text" id="serverDate" style="opacity: 20;" >
<script>
    let reloj = document.getElementById("serverDate");
    
    function muestraReloj () {
            fetch("reloj.php")
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(data => reloj.value = data); 
                console.log(reloj.value);
           var fechaYHora = new Date(reloj.value).toLocaleTimeString();
            console.log(fechaYHora);
    }
    setInterval(muestraReloj, 1000)
</script>
```

Everything works correctly for me, but I don't want to show the time that is printed in the echo of the clock file, in the example that I establish if I remove the echo then it fails because it does not show anything. The input with the id serverDate I can hide it but the echo of the file clock.php I don't know how it could be hidden, any ideas?

Comment: Why do you include `reloj.php` in your `index.php` file?

Comment: @ChrisG to bring the current date of the server, since when the php code that is in the file clock.php set it in the index, then it sent me all the HTML

Comment: Apparently thanks to your comment I realized that if I was shown this echo by <? Php include ("clock.php"); ?> then just delete it

Comment: Just to be clear: you don't need to include the file in order to be able to fetch it. (and you probably don't want to show *output* in an `<input>`)

Comment: Yes, including the file will insert the server time at the point in time the page was loaded. It gets inserted as plain text into your index.php document.

Comment: Final note: your question title does not describe the actual problem at all. You are getting it fine. The problem is something very different

Comment: simply you can create php function which will return date/time and you can get it any time like most of the time, we use it for timer and quize application. offcourse you have to make ajax call to that fucntion and get the latest time whenever you need.

Comment: Why don't you get the initial date/time and let javascript increase the returned value as a live clock? You probably will broke your server doing a one request per second.

Comment: just return the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']` variable to your frontend with a request. is that what you need?

Answer (score 0):

replace this with your Clock.php file content:

```
<?php
    echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
?>
```